# Using EFI_TCG2_PROTOCOL in UEFI

Tags: c, uefi, tpm, edk2

I try to use **EFI_TCG2_PROTOCOL** in UEFI to access TPM functionality.
I create persistent key in user space, using TSS API in this way:

```
// We will make a key in the "null hierarchy".
TPMT_PUBLIC primTempl(TPM_ALG_ID::SHA1,
    TPMA_OBJECT::decrypt | TPMA_OBJECT::userWithAuth | TPMA_OBJECT::sensitiveDataOrigin,
                      null,  // No policy
                      TPMS_RSA_PARMS(null, TPMS_SCHEME_OAEP(TPM_ALG_ID::SHA1), 2048, 65537),
                      TPM2B_PUBLIC_KEY_RSA());

// Create the key
auto storagePrimary = tpm.CreatePrimary(TPM_RH::OWNER, null, primTempl, null, null);

TPM_HANDLE& keyHandle = storagePrimary.handle;

// We can put the primary key into NV with EvictControl
TPM_HANDLE persistentHandle = TPM_HANDLE::Persistent(1000); //offset 1000

// First delete anything that might already be there
tpm._AllowErrors().EvictControl(TPM_RH::OWNER, persistentHandle, persistentHandle);

// Make our primary persistent
tpm.EvictControl(TPM_RH::OWNER, storagePrimary.handle, persistentHandle);

//// Flush the old one
tpm.FlushContext(storagePrimary.handle);
```

It works excellent and I can access this key even after reboot, so key is saved into non-volatile memory and can be reused later.
But when I try to access this key from UEFI, using **EFI_TCG2_PROTOCOL** for example calling function **TPM_CC_ReadPublic** for this key it doesn't return error code, but response not seems to be correct. Example:

```
struct TPM2_Read_Public_Command {
TPMI_ST_COMMAND_TAG     tag;
UINT32                  commandSize;
TPM_CC                  commandCode;
TPMI_DH_OBJECT          objectHandle;
};

struct TPM2_Read_Public_Response {
TPM_ST                  tag;
UINT32                  responseSize;
TPM_RC                  responseCode;
TPM2B_PUBLIC            outPublic;
TPM2B_NAME              name;
TPM2B_NAME              qualifiedName;
};
...
TPMI_DH_OBJECT hKeyHandle = PERSISTENT_FIRST + 1000; //offset 1000
struct TPM2_Read_Public_Command readPublicCmd = { 0 };
struct TPM2_Read_Public_Response readPublicResponse = { 0 };
...
readPublicCmd.tag = SwapBytes16(TPM_ST_NO_SESSIONS); //x86 is little endian, TPM2 is big-endian, use bswap to convert!)
readPublicCmd.commandSize = SwapBytes32(sizeof(struct TPM2_Read_Public_Command));
readPublicCmd.commandCode = SwapBytes32(TPM_CC_ReadPublic);
readPublicCmd.objectHandle = SwapBytes32(hKeyHandle);


Status = tcg2_protocol->SubmitCommand(
    tcg2_protocol,
    sizeof(struct TPM2_Read_Public_Command), (UINT8*)&readPublicCmd,
    sizeof(struct TPM2_Read_Public_Response), (UINT8*)&readPublicResponse
);

if (EFI_ERROR(Status))
{
    Print(L"keyReadPublicBuffer() FAILED, error = 0x%llX!\n", Status);
    //return Status;
}
else
{
    Print(L"keyReadPublicBuffer() SUCCESS!\n", Status);
    for (i = 0; i < SwapBytes16(OutPublic.publicArea.unique.rsa.size); i++)
    {
        Print(L"%X", OutPublic.publicArea.unique.rsa.buffer[0]);
    }
    Print(L"\nkeyReadPublicBuffer() SUCCESS!\n", Status);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you using byte allignment for the structs?

Comment: Yes. #pragma pack(push, 1) is defined before structures definitions and #pragma pack(pop) after.